# Analyzer showing warning on the line of allocation of property variables

Tags: iphone, memory-management

I am having a strange issue where the static analyzer throws a warning 'object allocated on line xxx is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)' on

```
self.myProperty = [[aClass alloc] initWithObject:anObject];
```

Since this is a property of my ViewController class, I need the object everywhere in the class and I am releasing the object in the dealloc method.

```
[myProperty release];
myProperty = nil;
```

At first I released the object in dealloc as

```
[self.myProperty release];
```

and at that time the warning on the allocation part was gone, but another one came up in the release line 'Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller'.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the setter for myProperty also retain the object? That might explain the leak warning.

Comment: yes Mihal, the myProperty object retain the object. So how should I fix this?

Comment: You probably want to release the object after setting the object. That way the object remains with a retain count of 1.

Comment: when I released the object after setting it, the app crashed.

Comment: In that case either the setter is not doing a retain or you are doing an extra release somewhere else; make sure all retain/releases are paired up.